# How to save a refernece to a checkbox in a table row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

After a checkbox has been checked I display a form. If the form is canceled, I wish to uncheck the box.

**EDIT**

On the table-form (second form), scroll over to the checkbox and check one, then go to the first form and click the Cancel button. Scroll back down to the box you checked.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g4evf26x/)

In the HTML, I define:

```
<input id="current-checkbox" type="checkbox" class="hidden" />
```

In the associated JS I save the current position:

```
var curRow = $(this).closest('.trow').find('input[type=checkbox]');
$("#current-row",curRow);
```

console.log shows:

```
$("#current-checkbox")
[<input id=​"current-checkbox" type=​"checkbox" class=​"hidden">​]
```

The cancel form JS:

```
$("#cancel-email").on('click', function (e) {
    debugger
    e.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(function () { showMessage(1, 'Emails not sent.') }, 2000);
    setTimeout(function () { hideEmailElems(); }, 2000);
    $("#current-checkbox").find("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", false).focus();
});
```

console.log:

```
$("#current-checkbox").find("input[type=checkbox]").length
0
```

What is the correct jQuery selector to locate saved the checkbox?

Comment: I can't follow your question. Create a CMVE

Comment: you don't need the `.find()` statements, the `id` selector will get one correct element.

Comment: You can use $("#current-checkbox").prop("checked", false).
No need to use .find() function or .closet() function for it.

Answer (score 1):

`$("#current-checkbox")` selects only one element (i.e. the checkbox), because it's a selector by id.

`find(selector)` method find *child* elements matching the selector within matched elements, so in this case  `$("#current-checkbox").find("input[type=checkbox]")` in empty, because that checkbox element doesn't have any child element.

Therefore, you won't need that `.find()` part. the `$("#current-checkbox")` is enough.

Note that in a valid HTML, [the id attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp) must be *unique*. So, id selectors match with at most one element.

> How to save a reference to a checkbox in a table row?

You wouldn't need to save a reference to the checked checkbox. You can instead by using `:checked` selector find it from anywhere.

```
$("#cancel-email").on('click', function(e) {
    // Un-check the checked checkbox
    $(".trow input[type=checkbox]:checked").prop("checked", false);

    // Hide the E-Mail box
    $('#main-container').hide();
});
```

Comment: Makes sense, but the box is still checked after implementing your solution (even though the console showed it did: $("#current-checkbox").prop("checked") false)?

Comment: @rontornambe Could you please create a minimal live demo?

Comment: Sorry for the tardy edit - am working from a hospital room. Sorry for the crude jsfiddle. Going into therapy, it may be a while before I can reply again, so take your time.

Comment: Bingo! Thanks. Please create an answer.

Comment: @rontornambe I'm glad I could help you. I'll update my answer.